# Ошибка в коде PHP

Tags: php

Есть код моя задача написать функцию что бы этот код работал

```
$all_products = $p->findAll();
$first = $all_products[0];
$first->name = "New name";
$first->save();
```

Вот эта функция

```
public function findAll() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM s_products";
    $this->result = mysql_query($query, $this->connect);
    $rez = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($this->result)) {
        $rez[] = $row;
    }

    return $rez;            
}  

public function save() {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `s_products` (`name`, `annotation`, `image`) VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->description', '$this->image')";
    $this->result = mysql_query($query, $this->connect);
    if ($this->result) {
        $this->id = mysql_insert_id();
    }           
}
```

У меня возникла ошибка в строке вызова ф-ции `$first->save();`

Помогите исправит ошибку

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: Ну так $first у вас обычный объект, возвращаемый функцией mysql_fetch_object(). Откуда у него возьмётся метод save()?

Answer (score 1):

```
$all_products = $p->findAll();
$first = $all_products[0];
$first->name = "New name";
$first->save();
```

Идём от противного.

```
class entry{
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $description;
  public $image;
  public $result;

  public function save() {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `s_products` (`name`, `annotation`, `image`) VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->description', '$this->image')";
    $this->result = mysql_query($query, $this->connect);
    if ($this->result) {
      $this->id = mysql_insert_id();
    }
  }
}
```

Тогда то, что нам возвращается из базы в методе findAll выглядит не совсем так.

```
...
public function findAll() {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM s_products";
  $this->result = mysql_query($query, $this->connect);
  $rez = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($this->result)) {
     $entry = new entry();
     $entry->$name = $row['name'];
     $entry->$description = $row['annotation'];
     $entry->$image = $row['image'];
     $rez[] = $entry;
  }

  return $rez;
}
...
```

---

Заметьте, что `findAll` и `save` - методы разных объектов в Вашем коде

---

Код с коленки, не пробовался м.б. ошибки:)

Answer (score 0):

$first->save() - явно метод класса. Не вижу где вы его создаете, и какова его структура